# R populate data frame in a loop not working

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I could not find answers that worked in a google search.
My dataframe is not populating I don't know why.  This seems simple but it is not working.  Can anyone help?

```
x<- 50:1
y<- -44:5

theDF <- data.frame(x,y)

# add new column
theDF["GName"] <- 'NA'

divToG <- function (a)
{
   counter = 1
   g_number = 1

   # loop to populate new column
   for (i in 1:nrow(theDF))
   {
      theDF$GName[i] = paste("GName", toString(g_number))  # NOT WORKING!
      g_number = g_number + 1
   }    
}

#call the function
divToG (theDF)
```

Why is it not populating `theDF$GName[i]`? If the loop is successful, the column should be `GName 1`, `GName 2`, `Gname 3`, etc instead of `NA`, but I cannot get it to change from `NA`.

Comment: I think you're actually trying to do `theDF$GName <- paste('GName', 1:nrow(theDF))`. Vectorized operations are preferable to loops in R.

Comment: how to vectorize it?  If I needed to put items 1 to 10 in group 1, items 11 to 21 in group 2 etc?

Comment: You mean like `paste('GName', rep(1:5, each = 10))`? You are just pasting a string to whatever is in the sequence; you just need to make the sequence look like you want.

Comment: that is what I was looking for, how to select it as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

you need to put in return command in the function:

```
divToG <- function (a)
{
  counter = 1
  g_number = 1

  # loop to populate new column
  for (i in 1:nrow(theDF))
  {
    theDF$GName[i] = paste("GName", toString(g_number))  # NOT WORKING!
    g_number = g_number + 1
  }    
  return(theDF)
}

head(divToG (theDF))
   x   y   GName
1 50 -44 GName 1
2 49 -43 GName 2
3 48 -42 GName 3
4 47 -41 GName 4
5 46 -40 GName 5
6 45 -39 GName 6
```

A more elegant way would be to do away with the function and just run:

```
theDF$GName <- paste("GName", 1:nrow(theDF))
```

Comment: `paste` is vectorized, so you don't need `sapply`—you can just stick `1:nrow(theDF)` directly into `paste`.

Answer (score 0):

If you `paste` a single string to a sequence of numbers, the numbers will be coerced to characters and the string will be pasted onto each. Thus, the first step is to get your sequence the way you want with `:`, `seq`, or occasionally `sequence`. If you're trying to make a grouping variable, `rep`'s `each` parameter is helpful:

```
rep(1:5, each = 3)
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5
```

Now just `paste` on a prefix (here with `paste0` for `sep = ""`):

```
paste0('GName', rep(1:5, each = 10))
#  [1] "GName1" "GName1" "GName1" "GName1" "GName1" "GName1" "GName1" "GName1" "GName1" "GName1"
# [11] "GName2" "GName2" "GName2" "GName2" "GName2" "GName2" "GName2" "GName2" "GName2" "GName2"
# [21] "GName3" "GName3" "GName3" "GName3" "GName3" "GName3" "GName3" "GName3" "GName3" "GName3"
# [31] "GName4" "GName4" "GName4" "GName4" "GName4" "GName4" "GName4" "GName4" "GName4" "GName4"
# [41] "GName5" "GName5" "GName5" "GName5" "GName5" "GName5" "GName5" "GName5" "GName5" "GName5"
```